# How to have fixed box shadow for background image under different screen width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a left box-shadow to the background image here, but there is a problem: on different screen width devices, the box-shadow effect will be different, e.g. on a narrow device, the shadow will cover the 'F' character, but on a wide device, the shadow would stick to the left and not cover any characters.

My question is: when screen width increases, how can I make the box-shadow fixed to the same position?

```css
div {
  background-image: url("https://www.textuar.com/blogold/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/free-images-for-copywriting.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 600px 0 500px -300px #292828;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Use percentage sizes on the shadow instead of pixels? Also, you'd get more control over a gradient background instead of a drop shadow and that seems closer to what you want.

Comment: @BryceHowitson your suggestion worked! Can you post an answer so I could accept it?